# Order of a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I need help showing this result:

"Let $G$ be a group such that $|G|=nm$ where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Suppose that there exists a normal subgroup H of G such that $|H|=n$.  Show that $H$ is the only subgroup with order $n$."

Can someone give me a light?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the order of the image of any alleged subgroup of order $n$ under the canonical map from $G$ to $G/H$.

Comment: Can I say that $|\pi (H')|=n$ ($\pi$ is the canonical map)? Because I think I should think about $ker (\pi)$ which, when restricted to $H'$ (where $H'$ is the group other than $H$ with order $n$) as being the intersection of $H$ and $H'$ which is not necessarily $\{1\}$.

Comment: If your notation means what I think it means, then $\pi(H')$ is a subgroup of $G/H$, and that has implications for its order.

Comment: Yes, then it must divide the order of $G/H$, but that does not mean that it must divide m or n because they are not prime numbers themselves.

Comment: And what is the order of $G/H$?

Comment: It must be $m$. I think I got this, but my mind is clouded with some (personal life) problems right now.

Comment: I mean, the order of $\pi(H')$ is $n$ minus the order of the intersection of $H$ and $H'$ (which is the kernel of $\pi$ when it is restricted to $H'$. If that's a divisor of $n$ then the exercise is over... but, must it be a divisor of $n$?

Comment: You're right to consider the kernel of $\pi$ when it is restricted to $H'$; let's call that kernel $K$. Then $\pi(H')$ is isomorphic to $H'/K$, which tells you what you need to know about its order.